# How to get the Path of my export-csv file powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I want get the Path of my exported CSV file and store it in a variable.

Here's my PowerShell code:

```
Get-ADUser -identity $sam | Select  @{ expression={$_.GivenName}; label='FirstName' }, @{ expression={$_.Surname}; label='LastName' }, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName | export-csv -Path "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv" -Append -Force
```

I am looking for to get the path of `NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv`

Comment: Did you tried: `$myPath = "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Export-Csv` creates the file in the current working directory, so you can construct the path like this if the file doesn't exist yet:

```
Join-Path $PWD.Path "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv"
```

If the file already exists you can resolve the path like this:

```
(Resolve-Path "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv").Path
```

or like this:

```
(Get-Item "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv").FullName
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a simple case of:

```
$Path = "NotMigratedUsers_$($DateofExport.Invoke()).csv"
```

But obviously I don't know (based on the code provided) what `$DateofExport` contains or whether it actually has an `Invoke()` method.